# ggplot2: how to reduce the number of items in a legend

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following function:

```
gg.barplots <- function(inp, order, xlab.strg, ylab.strg) {
  require(RColorBrewer)
  require(ggplot2)
  require(reshape2)
  arg <- c(expression(hat(p)[M]), expression(hat(p)[C]))
  p <- order
  col <- c(colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(9,'Blues')[2:9])(p+2), 
           colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(9,'Oranges')[2:9])(p+2))
  lab <- c(0:p, paste(">",p,sep=""))
  freq.mat <- data.frame(labels = lab, inp)
  names(freq.mat) <- c("x", "Magnitude-only", "Complex-valued")
  freq.mat$x <- factor(freq.mat$x, levels = c(levels(freq.mat$x)[-1],levels(freq.mat$x)[1]))
  ## force the orders to be as we want them to appear, using the factor function with levels specified. 
  freq.df <- melt(data = freq.mat, id.vars = 1, measure.vars = 2:3)
  fill.vars <- paste(rep(names(freq.mat)[-1], times = p), rep(freq.mat$x, each = 2), sep = ":")
  fill.vars <- factor(fill.vars, levels = fill.vars)
  freq.df <- data.frame(fill.vars, freq.df[rep(c(0,p+2), times = p + 2) + rep(1:(p + 2), each = 2), ])
  ggplot(data=freq.df, aes(x = x, y = value, fill = fill.vars)) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge(), colour = "black") +
    scale_fill_manual(values = col[rep(c(0,p+2), times = p + 2) + rep(1:(p + 2), each = 2)]) +
    theme_bw() +
    xlab(arg) +
    ylab(ylab.strg) +
    xlab(xlab.strg) +
    ylab(ylab.strg)
}
```

which gives me the following (two dodged barplots) as in the following example:

```
dput(out.AR2$AR.rate)
structure(c(0.25178, 0.06735, 0.64564, 0.03523, 0.04396, 0.0027, 
0.90415, 0.04919), .Dim = c(4L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(c("0", 
"1", "2", ">2"), NULL))
```

and calling the function:

```
gg.barplots(inp = out.AR2$AR.rate, order = 2, xlab.strg = "AR order", ylab.strg = "Proportions")
```

which results in the following figure:

[image]

Now I feel that (even ignoring the inherent ugliness of the current legend in this plot), the whole legend is not necessary. I think it is enought to have only the colors (say the mid-valye of the Oranges scale and the mid-value of the Blues scale) should be enough to represent the important parts of the plot. The remainder (AR orders in the legend) are already there in the figure.

My question: is how do I make a legend which has only these two colors (and the words Complex-value and Magnitude-only) associated with them? I have tried several things and I am a bit lost, sorry.

Comment: I think the problem is with the `scale_fill_manual` call. You should be able to separate the bar-type and the color-type legends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function is a little messy - you could probably split it into two functions, one to clean and one to plot.

Anyways, the easiest way to get what you want is to use the `breaks` argument to `scale_fill_manual`. This allows you to choose only those levels you want in the legend:

```
gg.barplots <- function(inp, order, xlab.strg, ylab.strg) {
  require(RColorBrewer)
  require(ggplot2)
  require(reshape2)
  arg <- c(expression(hat(p)[M]), expression(hat(p)[C]))
  p <- order
  col <- c(colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(9,'Blues')[2:9])(p+2), 
           colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(9,'Oranges')[2:9])(p+2))
  lab <- c(0:p, paste(">",p,sep=""))
  freq.mat <- data.frame(labels = lab, inp)
  names(freq.mat) <- c("x", "Magnitude-only", "Complex-valued")
  freq.mat$x <- factor(freq.mat$x, levels = c(levels(freq.mat$x)[-1],levels(freq.mat$x)[1]))
  ## force the orders to be as we want them to appear, using the factor function with levels specified. 
  freq.df <- melt(data = freq.mat, id.vars = 1, measure.vars = 2:3)
  fill.vars <- paste(rep(names(freq.mat)[-1], times = p), rep(freq.mat$x, each = 2), sep = ":")
  fill.vars <- factor(fill.vars, levels = fill.vars)
  freq.df <- data.frame(fill.vars, freq.df[rep(c(0,p+2), times = p + 2) + rep(1:(p + 2), each = 2), ])
  ggplot(data=freq.df, aes(x = x, y = value, fill = fill.vars)) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge(), colour = "black") +
    scale_fill_manual(values = col[rep(c(0,p+2), times = p + 2) + rep(1:(p + 2), each = 2)], breaks = c("Magnitude-only:2", "Complex-valued:2")) +
    theme_bw() +
    xlab(arg) +
    ylab(ylab.strg) +
    xlab(xlab.strg) +
    ylab(ylab.strg)
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! And i was further able to modify it to do what else I wanted!